# How to render menu using Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid

Is it possible to render a menu using Fluid, so that there is no html in TypoScript files? So far I have seen only getting the whole html menu via f:cObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the TypoScript cObjects normally return a rendered (as configured) representation (a string). In Fluid you iterate through objects or arrays. Therefore TypoScript und Fluid don't work together the way you'd like.

Have a look at the extension "vhs". It brings you the features you need, e.g. for a menu:
https://fedext.net/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/MenuViewHelper.html

With vhs you no longer need to define menus in TypoScript.